# Почему такая запись не работает?

Tags: html, css

Следующая запись не работает, нужно выбрать 4-ый `ul` и второй дочерний элемент `li`, как это возможно реализовать?
По возможности без применения JavaScript. Спасибо :)

```
.wrapper-filter .block-main-filter ul:nth-child(4) li:nth-child(2) label .radio__text:before,
.wrapper-filter .block-main-filter ul:nth-child(4) li:nth-child(2) label .radio__text:after {
    width: 68px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #696969;
    border-radius: 7.26556px;
}
```

Comment: Добавить бы пример HTML в вопрос. Так-то селектор вполне рабочий. Скорее всего nth-child неправильно использован)

Comment: Прошу прощения что ссылкой, там просто уже залил это добро в попытках сделать https://omb-shop.com/catalogue - Блок в фильтрах 'colors'

Файл в который залил эти строки внизу: https://omb-shop.com/catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/fix.css?ver=1.1

Comment: В последней версии Хрома (87-й) ссылка не работает, выдаёт ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Comment: @vsemozhebuty, у меня последняя тоже, вроде нет такой ошибки(

Comment: Элемента с классом wrapper-filter вообще нет на странице, к слову. Как и block-main-filter или radio__text

Comment: Он есть на странице, все четко с этим https://imgur.com/a/ZiX014H

Comment: Вы уверены что у нас отображается один и тот же контент? [imgur.com/a/jokyZFq](https://imgur.com/a/jokyZFq)

Comment: "нужно выбрать 4-ый `ul`" - для выполнения задачи именно так, лучше подойдёт [:nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type). К тому же, на вашем скриншоте в дереве есть элементы помимо ul на том же уровне